# Understanding the difference between htfp urls and hdfs path

Tags: hadoop, ftp, hdfs, cluster-computing, distcp

This difference comes to me during weekend, when I was trying to transfer bulk data across different clusters (physically separated in rooms) through `hftp` by doing

```
hadoop distcp hftp-path-src hftp-path-dst
```

`hftp` url is something like `hftp://node:50070/more/path`

It failed mid-way, on some files. Logs said

> Unhandled internal error. Vertex failed, vertexName=scope-152 ...

I checked those files manually and didn't find anything suspicious. I also tried the following foolish `Pig` script to see if it could surprise me

```
data = LOAD '$src_hftp' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
STORE data INTO '$dst_hftp' USING PigStorage('\t', '-schema');
```

, which failed miserably with the message

> "...DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE"

Now how about

```
hadoop distcp hdfs-path-src hdfs-path-dst
```

with `hdfs-path` being something like `hdfs://namenode:8020/more/path`.

It worked fine. What? Why?

Many many thanks in advance.

===========================================

In response to @rahulbmv's answer, I did try

```
hadoop distcp hftp-path-src hdfs-path-dst
```

which failed in the mid-way also, and I could see some of the transferred file on the `dst` HDFS, others missing. So I thought this's irrelevant. The reference I referred to was http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/4-x/4-7-1/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_7_2.html.

I also tried logging into `dst` namenode server and doing

```
hadoop distcp hftp-path-src normal-path-without-hdfs-or-hftp
```

Same error happened.

But yes, writing-port should use `hdfs` protocol. By using `hdfs` protocol, error persisted. After @rahulbmv has pointed out, the only difference was really the protocol the reader used. I will go back and dig the error messages up later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hftp is a read-only file system. So you cannot copy into a hftp destination. That said, you should be able to do `hadoop distcp hftp-path-src hdfs-path-dst` though.
You can read more about hftp and the operations that it supports [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Hftp.html).

Comment: can you post the error message that you received while running the command?